# How to plug in cell arrays in the x-axis of a plot?

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot

I would like to make a plot in which I will the x-axis contains the values of a cell array.

I am using R2019a.

```
t.Format = 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
time = cellstr(t)
A = randn(3,1)
figure;
filename = plot(datetime(time),A);
xlim([min(datetime(time)) max(datetime(time))])
```

As an output, I am getting a graph that contains dates and time in the x-axis. The desired output should be limited in showing only the dates.

Comment: Please do not delete the question after you have gotten an answer, as this is considered to be rude. If the answer helped you, consider accepting it, and if it did not, leave a comment on it explaining why it does not work, or asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`datetick`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html):

```
datetick('x','dd-mmm-yyyy')
```